# i'm searching for a way to improve this function that's basically doing the control of double input data type

Tags: java

this is my Function to control the double input from the user but it control only integer values if the user enter a comma ',' character like for example 100,300 it refuse to accept it so i'm thinking of doing the following : when the function encounter a comma character ',' it will change it to a dot character '.' and then i'm wondering if now the string value can be converted to a double like "100.300"
`

```
public static double controlDoubleInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
        String option = scanner.next();
        boolean isNotDigit = true;
        char[] array = option.toCharArray();
        do {
            for(char c : array) {
                if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    isNotDigit = false;
                }
                else {
                    isNotDigit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(isNotDigit) {
                System.out.println("input mismatch please retry : ");
                option = scanner.next();
                array = option.toCharArray();
            }
        } while(isNotDigit);

        return Double.parseDouble(option);
    }
```

`

Comment: Why do you not use `nextDouble()`?

Comment: Hello it's because i don't want the program to stop running i know that i can catch the expception but i don't know how to loop while cheking the exception for example if there is no exception then go out from the loop else continue demanding a double value from the user if you know how to do it help !

Comment: You can use `hasNextDouble()` to check if the next read of `nextDouble()` would be successful or not. Use this to either use `nextDouble()` or `next()` to skip over the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localization.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n")) {
    String option = scanner.next();
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
    while (true) {
         try {
                return nf.parse(option).doubleValue();
         } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("input mismatch please retry : ");
                option = scanner.next();
         }
     }
}
```